# Why doesn't the log4net XmlConfigurator attribute work for my unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, resharper, log4net, mstest

I'm using log4net, trying to get logging in my unit tests. If I manually call

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Since that works, that seems to eliminate all of the "bad config, config location" issues.

it works, but there are a large number of test classes, so that is not good.

I added

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

to the assemblyinfo of my test project, but when I run (either via native MSTest, or Resharper test runner) I get no logging.

Help?

Comment: Can clarify on where you added the `[assembly` line? Did you add it in an actual class?

Comment: its in assemblyinfo.cs in the properties folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20100726083431/http://blog.developerslog.net/?p=61)

```
[AssemblyInitialize()]
public static void MyTestInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
// Take care the log4net.config file is added to the deployment files of the testconfig
FileInfo fileInfo;
string fullPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "log4net.config");
fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [documentation for assembly attributes](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes)

> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
>   to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to
>   LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the calling assembly
>   to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging
>   call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
>   certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked**.

Because the unit test runners load the test assembly in order to find and the tests, it isn't possible to initialise log4net using an assembly attribute in unit test projects, and you will have to use the `XmlConfigurator`.

Edit: [as linked](http://web.archive.org/web/20100726083431/http://blog.developerslog.net/?p=61) in a comment by OP this can be done in one place for the whole test project by using the [AssemblyInitializeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx)

Comment: I didn't read that as a requirement, but jsut that you obviously would not be able to do any logging on parts that happened before it was loaded. Does having the assemblies loaded in some way stop log4net from reading the assembly attributes?

Comment: Yes, generally in the startup code of the primary assembly you would make a call to LogManager to load the assembly attributes. Once this has been done, assemblies that are subsequently loaded will be able to log. In the case of a unit test project, the test runner will load the assembly containing the unit tests, so the test runner is the primary assembly - and it isn't possible to get the test runner to read the attributes, and by the time the time the assembly containing the tests is loaded it seems it is too late to read the attributes.

Comment: I've found http://blog.developerslog.net/?p=61 which I will probablyh end up using, as thats still just once per assembly.